# How do I grant restricted permissions using adb?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-permissions

I need to grant '**android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**' permission.

Previously I used to use:`adb shell pm grant <PACKAGE_NAME> <PERMISSION>`.

This command is not working now with Android Q.

I realised that now android have added this permission into restricted category. when I do `adb shell dumpsys package <PACKAGE_NAME>`, I get:

```
      android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: restricted=true
      android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: restricted=true
...
...
...
        android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=false, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED|APPLY_RESTRICTION]
        android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=false, flags=[ USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_GRANTED|USER_SENSITIVE_WHEN_DENIED|APPLY_RESTRICTION]
```

[android developer doc for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

I've few questions where I need help:

1. How to fix this problem using code?
2. How can we grant these permission using adb?